# C++ update OpenGL/Glut window

Tags: c++, glut

I've tried some OpenGL C++ training.
But I have a logic problem, how can I update my OpenGL Windows window.
It should draw text one, then delay 1-2sec, then draw text 2, but now it draws same time. Can anyone help or give a hint.

```
void text () {  
    wait(1);
    Sleep(1000);
    std::string text_one;                                                                    
    text_one = "Text 1";                                                           
    glColor3f(1,01, 0);                                                                
    drawText(text_one.data(), text_one.size(), 050, 150);

    glutPostRedisplay();

    wait (1)
    std::string text_two;                                                                    
    text_two = "Text 2";                                                           
    glColor3f(1,0, 0);                                                                
    drawText(text_two.data(), text_two.size(), 250, 150);
}
```

and here the main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // init GLUT and create Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,640);
    glutCreateWindow("Test 001");

    // register callbacks

    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutIdleFunc(text);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render in renderScene callback. It will be called automatically in you screen refresh rate. If you want some delay you need to implement it inside this callback (functions called from this callback).

So basically you need to re-render everything every 1/60 second.

If you want to implement easy delay you can do something like this:

```
void renderScene() {
    time += deltaTime;
    RenderText1();
    if (time > delayTime) 
        RenderText2();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: You mena these glutDisplayFunc(renderScene); but if i dra two text layers they are appears all same time and not with delay. can i try the delay with windows  sleep and wait ? or should i take another way ?
Thanks for your time-  i tried the delay inside the renderscene callback but now it delays 2 sec for the first draw not between the draws.

Comment: Isn't the problem here that when glutSwapBuffers() is called, both the text are drawn to the scene at the same time? That's why the delay is just noticed between successive draws, at which point both the text are rendered.

Comment: @funkysidd Do you see delayTime? For some period of time we'll render only text 1, after that both texts.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa you are right! I somehow missed `delayTime`. This should work.

Comment: @funkysidd , yes i played around with the glutSwapBuffers.
And now i can draw text 1 and 3 same time and 2 alone continously.

Comment: Eventually is a frame rendering bette i want ry out a demonstration opengl/with music. and the target is animations effects for example fade in text .Other ways are welcome .

Comment: @uNkeLo If the answer helped you, accept it. If you have another question not related to this one ask another question and show us what have you tried.